# download a file from a server with kerberos authentication

Tags: shell, https, download, kerberos

I'm trying to script from a linux shell downloading a file from a webserver over https that is protected with with kerberos authentication. I've tried using wget and curl but neither of those seem to support kerberos over https.

Is there a linux commandline utility that supports kerberos over https? And if so how do you use it?

Comment: Sorry, not a programming question, voting to move to http://superuser.com/ OR you can 'flag' it and ask for a moderator to move it. (I didn't downvote your question). Good luck.

Comment: What about scripting makes this not a programming question? If this does need to move to a different site I think it would be better off at [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) than at [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)

Comment: You have a tooling problem not a programming problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the curl man pages. You can use --negotiate to use SPNego/GSSAPI/Kerberos. Most of the webservers support SPNego.

Answer (score 11):

It's entirely possible with curl if it has GSS-Negotiate. Check with `curl -V` it should return a *Features* line with *GSS-Negotiate* in it (Ubuntu 12.04 has it in package). You also need Kerberos client tools (like `krb5-user` on Ubuntu) and setup your `/etc/krb5.conf` with REALM and kdc. See [MIT docs](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html)

To begin with you must be able to get a ticket from the same KDC that the webserver uses (ignoring more complex possibilities). And also the domain you are going to GET from must have a proper reverse pointer or be configured in your `/etc/hosts` so check your DNS.

Start with `kinit <some user principal>`

Then you can curl your way to the URL you want to check. A *fake* user is required for curl to accept your negotiate (but not actually used, doesn't matter what username or password.) I also use a `--trace-ascii-` to get the Kerberos errors.

For example:

```
 curl  --negotiate -u foo --trace-ascii -  http://intranet/
```

If you see:

```
== Info: gss_init_sec_context() failed: : Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found<= Recv header, 29 bytes (0x1d)
```

Then you forgot `kinit` or it didn't succeed.

If you see something like that but with `krb5kdc_err_s_principal_unknown` then the name that the kerberos library constructed with a reverse pointer or host entry has no corresponding principal at the KDC contacted.

Otherwise if the server sends the proper `HTTP/1.1 401: Authorization Required` and `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate` you get authenticated.

Comment: Great answer. Any public yum repositories that have curl/libcurl with GSS-Negotiate prebuilt?

Comment: In Fedora 29, this works for me but prompts for a password (which then can be anything). Instead of using `foo`,  use `-u:` (with the `:` being a blank fake username _and password_).

Comment: Interesting. Could it be that the webserver also sent a WWW-Authenticate: Basic header?

Answer (score 1):

`curl` has SPNEGO support if you compile it with `fbopenssl`, there is no builtin support. I have done that and it works.

Comment: There's a comment in [curl's RPM .spec](http://subversion.city-fan.org/repos/cfo-repo/curl/trunk/curl.spec) file that states this as of version  7.38.0: "  - no longer use fbopenssl for anything".

Comment: @slm That is correct me and some others have dramatically improved curl's SPNEGO support back then.

Comment: Thanks for doing that, it wasn't entirely clear when I started trying to build 7.37 until I found the .spec file and then realized that in later versions, 7.38+ that SPNEGO is now easier to build since the requirement of having to get FBOpenSSL has been removed. Given this should this answer be updated to reflect the current state or to clarify that it's different depending on which version of curl you're using?

Comment: @slm. True. Go ahead and edit my answer. I will approve the change.